# Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'xxx'

Tags: c#, .net, iis, extjs

i get this error

```
Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'charts.lineChartData'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="lineChartData.ashx.cs" Class="charts.lineChartData" %>

Source File: /WebSiteNetPas/lineChartData.ashx    Line: 1 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

in fact i get this error when using fiddler , my original error is :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lineChartData is not defined                   lineChart.js:20
http://localhost/WebSiteNetPas/lineChartData.ashx?proxy 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

here is my **lineChartData.ashx.cs** :

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace charts
{
    public class lineChartData : IHttpHandler
    {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        { return false; }
    }

    static string ConvertToJson()
    {
        lineChartClass c = new lineChartClass();

        double[] json = new double[4];

        //Array.Copy(c.piedata(), json, 4);
        c.piedata().CopyTo(json, 0);

        List<ChartItem> chartItems = new List<ChartItem>();

        chartItems.Add(new ChartItem() { Name = "Low", Data1 = json[0].ToString() });
        chartItems.Add(new ChartItem() { Name = "Moderate", Data1 = json[1].ToString() });
        chartItems.Add(new ChartItem() { Name = "Critical", Data1 = json[2].ToString() });
        chartItems.Add(new ChartItem() { Name = "High", Data1 = json[3].ToString() });
        string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(chartItems);
        //result = "{ name: \"Low\", data1: " + json[0] + "}" + ",{ name: \"Moderate\", data1: " + json[1] + "}" + ",{ name: \"Critical\", data1: " + json[2] + "}" + ",{ name: \"High\", data1: " + json[3] + "}";

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

if u need more details just let me know

thanks in advance for ut time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this.. fixed it.. thought I'd share

if you right click the .asmx file and select view markup you'll see it still says

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyService.asmx.cs" Class="MyProject.Service1" %>
```

maybe not Service1.. but won't be the class you've just made

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyService.asmx.cs" Class="MyProject.MyService" %>
```

save it.. try it..

worked for me..

Comment: Also beware that text in the Class attribute is case sensitive: Class="MyProject.MyService" is different to Class="MyProject.myService". I was caught out with this myself.

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this error using Visual Studio Development Server when my project output directory was not bin\

One of my DLLs has versions for different platforms (x86, x64), so I created corresponding configurations, and they got by default output directories like this:

```
bin\x86\Debug 
bin\x64\Debug
```

But the Visual Studio Development Server still tried to load binaries from the bin\ folder and of course failed.

I fixed the issue by specifying bin\ output folder in my debug configurations.

Comment: After digging around for a while this was the fix that did it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You usually get that when your code doesn't build, i.e. there is no dll so i can't load the handler type.

Comment: but i did build the project, and the dlls are there i didnt change directory or anything

Comment: i think so.;how do i make sure of it?

Comment: @Astrocybernaute - Check the settings on the project.

Comment: The problem is that it can't load the type for the handler file.  If the DLLs are there and they are the correct version, then it looks like the DLLs don't contain the type for the handler, i.e. they are old DLLs.  Rebuild and redeploy the website.

Comment: ive done so without results,thx anyway,i'll accept ur answer just to close this because i changed this whole method

Comment: @astrocybernaute, Wow. You accepted an answer that doesn't work?

Comment: @ Ben Robinson Thanks