# Parser Error Message: Could not create type .ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, iis, ashx

I have made a very simple WebService. I made a website on IIS server and uploaded the code there. But I get the error below. I googled it but I couldn't find a solution that works. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Thanks.

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'DictWebAPI.DictHandler'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="DictHandler.ashx.cs"
>   Class="DictWebAPI.DictHandler" %>
>
> Source File: /dictwebapi/dicthandler.ashx    Line: 1

My ashx.cs file looks like this :

```
namespace DictWebAPI
{

    public class DictHandler : JsonHandler
    {

        public DictHandler()
        {
            this.service.Name = "DictWebAPI";
            this.service.Description = "JSON API for Dict Application";
            InterfaceConfiguration IConfig = new InterfaceConfiguration("RestAPI", typeof(IServiceAPI), typeof(ServiceAPI));
            this.service.Interfaces.Add(IConfig);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could be that the type `DictWebAPI.DictHandler` and class `DictWebAPI.SozlukHandler` don't match up

Comment: Well this link maybe help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760489/parser-error-message-could-not-create-type-xxx

Comment: @DGibbs I fixed the code, all are "dict"s

Comment: Did you rebuild / compile?

Comment: What is the file name of your ashx.cs?

Comment: @PatrickHofman DictHandler.ashx.cs

Comment: Does the application pool's .NET version match the project one?

Comment: @codroipo yes. both are 4.0

Comment: Does the bin directory contain the dll of your project?

Comment: @codroipo yes. it has all.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but I had the same issue and managed to resolve it so thought I'd share!

The issue in my code is that I had copied and pasted the .ashx file to another file, though forgot to change the `Class` value in the directive:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="UnsubUser" %>
```

Both files had the same Class name listed and so was triggering the error. Simply fixing the Class names in all files corrected the issue.